# How to close a window in which a mail containing confirmation link is opened by clicking on the link

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer, email-client

I am sending a email id confirmation mail to user on signup using nodemailer.A new window pops up as the user clicks on signup button with the mail servive provider(eg : www.gmail.com). I want to close the new opened window when user clicks on the confirmation link provided in the mail on their gmail account.

I tried sending self.close() method in html tag in the mail but it is not working. Providing the code for the same

Please can someone help me. Thanks in advance!!

`var mailOptions = {
      from: 'vijayendracourse@gmail.com',
      to: 'vijayendrapagare05@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Confirm your mail id',
      html : '<a href="http://localhost:3000/confirmemail?user_id='+id+'" onclick="self.close()">click here</a>'

    };`

Comment: Javascripts dont work in emails so closing the tab/window after a task is done might not work

Comment: Please could you suggest some other approach @Syfer

Comment: There is no other approach with what you are trying to do. Best would be to have a link to a page and do everything on that window. Self closing tabs/windows are not good.

Comment: okay. Thank you @Syfer